# Manually compile VB6 project using LINK.EXE and C2.EXE

Tags: compilation, linker, vb6, windows-10

I would like to try and avoid the VB6.exe application when trying to compile my project.  It tends to create the *.obj files and then crashes leaving me with no idea what went wrong.

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE" /m MyProject.vbp
```

I would like to try and use `LINK.exe` and `C2.exe` to compile my application instead.  I found a really [great article located here](http://www.brainbell.com/tutors/Visual_Basic/The_Linker.htm) on the process with all the switches etc.  I was hoping someone has tried something link this and been successful so they can tell me exactly what switches I need to use and a step by step process of how to create the object files and then link them all to the EXE.

Comment: Have you tried the /out and /outdir flags when you are doing the build using VB6.  Your command line would be something like "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE" /m MyProject.vbp /out c:\output\errorLog.txt /outdir c:\output\  .  That should log any errors you get in the build.

Comment: C2.exe is the 2nd pass and code generator of the compiler.  You need VB6.exe to perform pass 1 of the compile.

Comment: What options are you selecting in the build dialog (when you do try to compile via the IDE)

Comment: @BillHileman I was looking for all the default values on that.  `Compile to Native Code`-`Optimize for Fast Code`, `DLL Base Address: &H11000000`, No checks on `Advanced Optimizations`.

Comment: Have you tried compiling to p-code?  That might not be your desired end-result, but I wonder if it has the same results.

Comment: @Bob77 yea I figured I would have to let VB6.exe build the object files.  It gets that far then crashes when it starts linking from what I can tell.  So I have the project, source, all the object files that have been generated.  I now just need to link them all together and then use C2.exe I guess?  That's the answer I'm looking for...  One that walks me through the process of doing it manually once I use VB6.exe to generate the object files.  I'm guessing I would use the `LINK.EXE` command for EACH object file next...

Comment: @BillHileman I have in the past and sometimes that worked on some of the controls I was compiling when native would not.  In this case with this project that did not work either.  It's really hit or miss with the compile...  The crazy thing is sometimes I can indeed compile it just fine as I normally would.  But the stars have to be aligned and it's always different for every project.

Comment: @lardymonkey I had no clue I could create an error log like that!!!  I'll give that a shot as soon as I can.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I ended up getting this old source to compile.  I'm sure my situation was unique but I thought I would share in hopes of helping someone else find their way if this happens to them.

First, I could NOT get this one project to compile to save my life in the end.  At first it would compile in the IDE, then only by running the following in a command line...

```
"c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\VB98\VB6.EXE" /m MyProject.vbp
```

Then that would not even work and I had to use the package and deployment wizard to compile it which worked some of the time.

I think it was really just hit or miss in the end.  But at some point something pointed to a specific module file I had that was used to access (read/write) the registry.  I think it was between looking at logs and maybe even the windows event viewer etc.  So I started thinking...  Maybe it will compile if that was not used.  So I removed the module from the project, tried to compile, then VB was nice enough to show me every call that would not work because the referenced function did not exist.  I commented out all of those as well then I was able to compile with very little effort and it went smooth again!

So that helped me identify what VB was flipping out about but it did not solve the underlining issue (that I could not compile ALL of my source).  So I started trying to work all the source back into the application one by one to see where it would break at.

1. I first added the module file to the project and just compiled.

   ```
   Success!
   ```
2. I then tried to uncomment the first thing I commented out (reference to the function in that module) and then recompiled.

   ```
   Success!
   ```
3. I managed to get all the way back through all my commented out lines of code and put them back the way they were originally.  I then recompiled for the final time.

   ```
   Success!
   ```

So at this point I had EVERYTHING back to the exact way I had it before I started trying to compile.  Now it works with no issues at all!

Comment: I was going to accept this as the answer then figured that was a bad idea.  The question I asked was a tutorial of sorts to show how to manually compile the VB6 project (without the help of VB6.exe).  I'm just hoping my experience in my answer helps others find a solution to the issue of VB6 crashing when it tries to compile projects.

Comment: It would be cool to see a diff between all the project files (including the VBP) before and after this process. Something had to be different, somewhere. Maybe the difference would lie elsewhere, such as in the registry or a .vbw file...

Comment: I might try to spend some time looking into that.  If I do I will append to this answer.

Comment: Good news and bad news.  Good news is I have a copy of the non working and working project folders.  I spent a while comparing them, making changes to the bad project and trying to get it to compile mimicking changes to the project file from the good project.  The bad news, VB6 is so unpredictable is madding!  At some point without any changes made to the good project, it stopped compiling!  The only way to make it work again was to repeat my answer's instructions above.  I used to love VB6 back in the day.  Now I live for the day when I can rewrite everything in c#...

Comment: Sounds like something in the registry may get "corrupted" and then breaks your build? Gotta be something outside of the project files which is being changed. I feel your pain!!

Comment: I agree.  It seems like it happens as soon as I close VB6.  Even if I do not save the project on exit.  I can compile as many times as I want with no errors, even save project and continue to compile with no errors.  But when I exit and open back up...  Can not compile until I take out the calls to the registry module, compile once then put them back.  After that I can rinse and repeat.  Ironically, that's consistent.

Comment: OK I think I just found something!...  If I open it back up and make NO changes then try to compile, it fails.  If I comment out ONE single line of code or change something, save and recompile it works.

Comment: Try to disable all IDE plugins.

Comment: @wqw first thing I tried a long time ago.  That's not the issue.  All I had was MZtools and I tried to disable that.  Even tried to uninstall it.  The onlything that works at this point is to actually make a change in the source before compiling the code.  If you open and compile successfully, you can continue to compile as much as you want (changes or not).  But when you close it, reopen the project and try to compile something in which the source has not changed VB6 crashes.  I'm not saying I have found a fix but I guarantee VB6 will not crash for that reason again!

Comment: Is this a multi-project group or a single Std-Exe project?

Comment: Single, so the registry cleanup trick has no impact.  But no that registry key is not present.  ;)